# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC Missing default action for all controllers except HomeController

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I use ASP.NET Core 5 MVC and I have an interesting issue. When I want load the `Index` method of any controller, then I have to write index action name into URL too. If i write only controller name into the URL, then it load nothing. I don't get any exception. I haven't folder in root directory with name what matching with any controller name. I use default routing, so i don't understand what is the problem. But i noticed an interesting stuff while debugging. I tried set a custom route path with data-annotation. When I renamed the controller, then I get an `AmbiguousMatch` exception.

> "AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
> Matches:
>
> CanteenFeedback2._0.Controllers.AdminPanelController.Login
> (CanteenFeedback2.0)
> CanteenFeedback2._0.Controllers.AdminPanelController.EditQuestion
> (CanteenFeedback2.0)
> CanteenFeedback2._0.Controllers.AdminPanelController.Statistic
> (CanteenFeedback2.0)
> CanteenFeedback2._0.Controllers.AdminPanelController.GetStatistic
> (CanteenFeedback2.0)
> CanteenFeedback2._0.Controllers.AdminPanelController.Index
> (CanteenFeedback2.0)
> CanteenFeedback2._0.Controllers.AdminPanelController.AuthError
> (CanteenFeedback2.0)
> CanteenFeedback2._0.Controllers.HomeController.Index
> (CanteenFeedback2.0)"

A detail from `AdminPanelController`:

```cs
public class AdminPanelController : Controller
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext DB;

    public AdminPanelController(DatabaseContext dB)
    {
        DB = dB;
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string userName = User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).First().Value;
        string lastName = User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName).First().Value;

        bool exists = false;
        string userId = User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).First().Value;
        if (DB.IdmAccounts.FirstOrDefault(i => i.AccountId == userId) != null)
        {
            exists = true;
        }
        else
        {
            exists = false;
        }

        IEnumerable<Category> categories;
        IEnumerable<Subcategory> subcategories;
        IEnumerable<Question> questions;

        try
        {
            categories = DB.Categories;
            subcategories = DB.Subcategories;
            questions = DB.Questions
                .Where(q => q.isArchived == false)
                .Include(q => q.Categories)
                .Include(q => q.Subcategories)
                    .ThenInclude(sc => sc.Category);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return Content("Nem sikerült betölteni a kérdéseket");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Content("Nem sikerült betölteni a kérdéseket");
        }

        ViewBag.lastName = lastName;
        ViewBag.exists = exists;

        ViewBag.categories = categories;
        ViewBag.subcategories = subcategories;
        ViewBag.questions = questions;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SessionSave(string token)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("JWToken", token);

        return Redirect("http://localhost:5000/AdminPanel/Index");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult AuthError()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And a detail from `HomeController`:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Cookie options
        CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
        cookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);

        // Add default cookie
        Response.Cookies.Append("lang_cookie", Languages.HU.ToString(), cookieOptions);

        // Setting language to view
        Language language = new Language(Pages.Home, Languages.HU);
        
        return View(language.GetPageTexts());
    }

    [Route("{changedLan}")]
    public IActionResult Index(Languages changedLan)
    {
        // Cookie options
        CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
        cookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
        
        // Update cookie
        Response.Cookies.Append("lang_cookie", changedLan.ToString(), cookieOptions);
        Language language = new Language(Pages.Home, changedLan);

        return View(language.GetPageTexts());
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly URL you entered when received the `AmbiguousMatchException` error? Can you add the `endpoints.MapControllerRoute()` to the post, please?

Comment: Please provide your Startup class.

Comment: Pls share your Startup.cs or Program.cs how do you define the route template. Then for the HomeController, pls modify the route attribute. It does not make sense to pass complex model by route. You can simply use `[Route("changedLan")]` which request url is: `https://localhost:portNumber/changedLan?LanguagesPropertyName1=yourvalue1&LanguagesPropertyName2=yourvalue2`.